# Stop Submit Button From Submitting Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a cancel button on my MVC 5 View which when clicked, I want to hide/show a couple of DIVs, but also, I don't want the form to submit.

This is the cancel button.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnCancelConsultant" name="btnCancelConsultant" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel Update">
```

I have this JQuery code which is supposed to be called when the user clicks the cancel button, however, it doesn't get called at all. I know this because the alert prompt doesn't happen. Instead, the form gets submitted, which is what I don't want to happen.

```
$("btnCancelConsultant").click(function () {

    alert("Cancel Called");
    //Show Add button, hide Update/Cancel button
    $("#AddConsultant").hide('fast');
    $("#UpdateConsultant").show('fast');

    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
    //return false;

});
```

I also tried replacing the first line of my JQuery function with

```
$("btnCancelConsultant").on('click', function () {
```

But this too still submits the form.

I don't understand why the form is submitting whenever I have tried using both

```
e.preventDefault(); 
return false;
```

To stop the submit from happening.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Missing `#` in `$("btnCancelConsultant")`. prevent it in form `submit` event.

Comment: It's `$("#btnCancelConsultant")`, and if you're going to use the event argument, you have to actually add it to the function

Comment: Did you try to change the type of input from "submit" to "button"?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sleepy eyes forgetting to put the # before btnCancelConsultant. A very harsh down vote however, every coder has missed small mistakes like this. Some people on this site are too quick down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

Use,

```
<input type="button" id="btnCancelConsultant" name="btnCancelConsultant" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel Update">
```

JS

```
$("#btnCancelConsultant").click(function (e) { //Added event argument
    //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your event to this, to accept event parameter in this case `e`:

```
$("#btnCancelConsultant").click(function (e) {

    alert("Cancel Called");

    $("#AddConsultant").hide('fast');
    $("#UpdateConsultant").show('fast');

    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default


});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btnCancelConsultant").click(function () {

alert("Cancel Called");
//Show Add button, hide Update/Cancel button
$("#AddConsultant").hide('fast');
$("#UpdateConsultant").show('fast');

e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
//return false;
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be:

```
$("#btnCancelConsultant").click(function (e) { // <-- don't forget this one
    // your code ...

    e.preventDefault();   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using on submit instead of on click

```
$( "#btnCancelConsultant" ).submit(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing an `e` from your code. This will pass the event through into the click function to the variable `e` so that you can stop the default by using `e.preventDefault()`.

You're also missing a `#` from your selector. You need this to search for an element with id of "btnCancelConsultant" instead of an element by that name. So instead you would need `$("#btnCancelConsultant")`.

So your code would become:

```
$("#btnCancelConsultant").click(function (e) {

    alert("Cancel Called");
    //Show Add button, hide Update/Cancel button
    $("#AddConsultant").hide('fast');
    $("#UpdateConsultant").show('fast');

    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
});
```